# Disable turbolink in a specific Rails page with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, turbolinks

I have an issue in a specific page of the app, that is fixed when turbolink is disabled. I know that adding `data-no-turbolink` as a body attribute fixes that, but I don't want turbolink to be disabled everywhere.

So, the best solution is to use something like `content_for` in the specific view that has the issue (I'm using HAML):

```
- content_for :body, "data-no-turbolink"
```

But it doesn't work (the page load with the content, no error but there is no `data-no-turbolink` in the body tag, and the issue is still live.)

I also tried this, with no success:

```
application.html.haml:
    %body{ yield(:body_attr) if content_for?(:body_attr) }

my_view.html.haml:
    - content_for :body_attr, "data-no-turbolink"
```

How can I add an attribute to `<body>` from a view? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A little late to solve htaidirt issue, but for anyone else struggling I've just had and solved this issue with the following.

Layout

```
%body{ no_turbolink? }
```

Helper

```
  def no_turbolink?
    if content_for(:no_turbolink)
      { data: {no_turbolink: true} }
    else
      { data: nil }
    end
  end
```

View

```
content_for :no_turbolink, true
```

Hope this helps, 
Chris.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= content_for :body_attr, data: { no_turbolink: true } %>`. Or try adding this attribute to the outer block.

Comment: The problem with the second try is that it produces an error dur to the `yield` in the body tag: `undefined method `map' for "{&quot;data-no-turbolink&quot;=&gt;true}":ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`